Found this in HVAC air duct (filter/suction side). What is it?
It has been in HVAC airduct since I bought the house. It was on filter/suction side. At this time the orange substance neither had scent nor was sticky.
What could it be?


Looks to me like a kid's art project that got dropped into the vent ;)

Those were sent papers that were supposed to add a pleasant smell to the air. They usually lasted only a few days.  It was probably left there by mistake., and the scent is long gone.

@RMDman typo: "scent", presumably.

@keshlam,  Yes, always was a poor speller.  Typing on only 3hrs sleep doesn't help. Thanks for the catch.

@RMDman  Did you safely survive Milton?

@Jack, Thanks for asking.  My condo was ok. Everything messy and all kinds of debris around of course. Finally got power back yesterday.  No cable or internet yet.   We went through the eye. Landfall was .7 a mile west of us. Wind was unbelievable. Two of my rentals lost the roofs. That place has no power or water.  it looks like the apocalypse happened.  But wife and I are alive and well and we can sleep in our own bed. so we are blessed.  How did you fair?

@RMDman  So sorry you got whacked so bad but glad you and the wife are OK.   We're in the Pembroke Pines area. had a lot of wind and little rain and two tornados two miles away...  but no damage and never lost power or cable so very lucky.

@Jack, now comes the icky part. I cleaned by my entryway today and the smell of death was in the air.  Never think about it but there were small animals that got caught in this and are now dead in the debris.  ICK...I buried 3 squirrels today. The front side was rain and wind. It plastered al kinds of debris on the walls. Then came the back side that was all wind. and it dried the stuff, so it's like ground vegetable debris stuck on the walls like they were flypaper.

@RMDman  Hang in there good buddy and stay safe and be careful.
